# UnityWebRequest - Loading Many Audio Files For Rhythm Game Is Slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, unitywebrequest

Function to load audio in LoadFile.cs:

```
public async Task<AudioClip> LoadAudioFile(string path) // Loads *.mp3's
{
    //Load audio from the chosen *.mp3 file
    using UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(path, AudioType.MPEG);
    var operation = www.SendWebRequest();

    while (!operation.isDone)
        await Task.Yield();

    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        return DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Calling the function in TrackLoader.cs:

```
beatmap.music = await LoadFile.instance.LoadAudioFile(Path.Combine(folderPath, beatmap.musicName));
```

Users are able to create their own custom levels in the rhythm game I'm developing, meaning they can **import their own** audio, art for the song, etc. I load audio with the above method (and essentially the same way with images).

Loading a 4 minute *.mp3 takes around **300-450ms** on my good computer when I run this. In the game, loading the songs when I enter the song select scene can take up minutes which is far too long. I'm not sure how to implement a better solution.

Games such as osu!mania and Quaver have **instant** access to the music, and the best guess I have is the music is being streamed instead of loaded all at once then played.

I attempted to Google how to do this but I'm stumped. How can I speed up this process?

If there is anything I missed I will be happy to provide anything at all.

**Reason for needing this: To be able to preview songs in song select.**

[VIDEO SHOWING HOW SLOW LOADING CURRENTLY IS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5-aH16i6Cc)

I understand there may be design flaws with this such as not background loading before switching to the song select scene, loading what is clicked, etc. However, even with those implemented I believe it won't achieve the quickness I need such as how Quaver has it. I don't know why the FPS is so low and why the debugger keeps going even after exiting play mode.

Comment: Well I'd say before a user actually clicks on one of these you do **not** want to load anything at all ... you just want to **list** available file locations (evtl meta data etc) but not actually load the entire audio clip. You start loading/streaming the audio data itself once a user has selected one ... Also why use a `Task` instead of a Coroutine?

Comment: @derHugo The issue is that, when the user has selected one, it takes far too long for the audio to begin playing (300-450ms). Games like Quaver do it instantly and at any point in the song. I used a Task because it allowed me to call the function from a singleton called LoadFile.cs in multiple scripts since I need to load audio in multiple scenes. I tested with Coroutines and they were the same time

Comment: why I ask is: Unity is not thread-safe and using Tasks you never know on which thread the Task finishes. With a Coroutine you know that it is only pocessed within the Unity main thread `Update` routine

Comment: @derHugo I've switched to Coroutines, but unfortunately by main issue still remains--it takes around 500ms now.